# When do events fire in solidity?

Tags: solidity

Suppose we have the following contract in solidity:

```
contract C {

event EventAdd_One(int a, int b);

event EventAdd_Two(int a, int b);

function add(int a, int b) returns (int) {

    // This fires every time
    EventAdd_One(a, b);

    if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        return a + b;
        // Does this fire every time?
        EventAdd_Two(a, b);
    } else return 0;
}

}
```

Does the second event fire regardless if **a** and **b** are positive?

Comment: I did not try reproducing, but it looks like `EventAdd_Two` will never fire because it comes after a `return`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are fired when the instruction to fire them is run, like any other. The means that `EventAdd_Two` won't fire, as the instruction is never reached - it returns before that.

This is the correct way:

`f (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        EventAdd_Two(a, b);
        return a + b;
    } else return 0;`

It will fire every time both `a` and `b` are positive. An example of the contract running in [browser-solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=0.3.6) can be seen in this image (look to the bottom right to see the events that were fired):
[image]